# How to get ForestTrustDomainInformation for a domain using Active Directory C# API

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I am interested in [ForestTrustDomainInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.foresttrustdomaininformation?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) for a domain object. But I am unable to find a C# API that I can use the retrieve this information.

How can I retrieve the `ForestTrustDomainInformation` for a domain that I am interested in? I went through a bunch of Active Directory documentation. But I couldn't find a way to retrieve this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not used with a `Domain` object, but from a `Forest` object, since it contains information for a trust between forests.

Assuming you have a [`Forest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.forest) object, you can use [`GetTrustRelationship()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.forest.gettrustrelationship) with the name of the other forest. That returns a [`ForestTrustRelationshipInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.foresttrustrelationshipinformation) object, that has a [`TrustedDomainInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectory.foresttrustrelationshipinformation.trusteddomaininformation) property that contains a list of `ForestTrustDomainInformation` objects.